# Function to Return Smallest Value (Python)

Tags: python, list, function, return

I need help on a programming assignment. I am completely lost on this one. If anyone could help, that would be great. The programming language is in Python.

Write a function called smallest() that will take three numbers as parameters and return the smallest value. If more than one number tied for smallest, still return that smallest number.   DO NOT use the built in min() Python function to do this.

```
6,3,5 -> 3
4,4,8 -> 4
3,7,2 -> 2
1,8,9 -> 1
9,0,6 -> 0
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about your assignment.  Questions that merely consist of copy/pasting your homework assignment are not on-topic here.

Comment: Non-attempts and "I can haz teh codez plz" questions beget cryptic code that your prof will know you didn't write: `with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile: outfile.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in (max([int(i) for i in line.strip().split(',')], key=lambda x:-x) for line in infile)))`

Comment: `map(lambda x:x[0] if x[1] >= x[0] <= x[2] else x[1] if x[0] >= x[1] <= x[2] else x[2],map(lambda line:map(int,line.split()) ,open('text.txt')))`

Comment: Nice @JoranBeasley. Building on that: `open('output.txt', 'w').write('\'.join(map(lambda x:x[0] if x[1] >= x[0] <= x[2] else x[1] if x[0] >= x[1] <= x[2] else x[2],map(lambda line:map(int,line.strip()split(',')) ,open('text.txt')))))`. Feel like we should make a "best of" series for this sort of thing on SO

Comment: but you forgot an `n` I think ;P

Comment: A 2-argument "smaller" is easy: `def smaller(x, y): return x if x<y else y`. Then `def smallest(values): return reduce(smaller, values)`. Or just `smallest = partial(reduce, smaller)`. Either way, tiny, and trivial. If you turned that in, and I were your teacher, I'd give you an A if you could explain why it works, and an F if you couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Well you didn't say you can't use the builtin *max* function, so

```
def smallest(*args):
    return max(*args, key=lambda x:-x)
```